# Core Data with Swift two entities

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to use Core Data to save some of my application data. I have following classes. Basically I want to store the properties of each job, and use it later on.

Following is the class I currently use in my application.

```
class Job {
    var name:String?
    var count = 1
    var id:String
    var startDate:NSDate?
    var finishDate:NSDate?
    var expected:NSDate?
    var detail:Array<JobDetail> = []
    var isFinished:Bool?
    var sender:String?
    var receiver:String?

    init(name:String?, id:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.isFinished = false
        self.startDate = NSDate()
    }

    func addDetail (message:String?, date:NSDate?, location:String?, status: DetailStatus) {
        detail.append(JobDetail(message: message, date: date, location: location, status: status))
        if status == DetailStatus.OK {
            self.isFinished = true
            self.finishDate = date
        }
    }

}


enum DetailStatus {
    case OK
    case Error
    case Exception
    case Unknown
}


class JobDetail {
    var message:String?
    var date:NSDate?
    var location:String?
    var status:DetailStatus

    init(message:String?, date:NSDate?, location:String?, status: DetailStatus) {
        self.message = message
        self.date = date
        self.location = location
        self.status = status
    }
}
```

NSManagedObject sub class I created with Xcode after I create the data model.

```
class Job: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var count: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var startDate: NSDate
    @NSManaged var finishDate: NSDate
    @NSManaged var expected: NSDate
    @NSManaged var isFinished: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var sender: String
    @NSManaged var receiver: String
    @NSManaged var details: NSSet

}

class JobDetail: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var message: String
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate
    @NSManaged var location: String
    @NSManaged var status: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var parent: Job

}
```

Here are the screenshots of my data model.

[image: Job]
[image: Job Detail]
Basically I want to CRUD Job in my application so that I can show them in my tableview. I have everything setup, but because I couldn’t setup Core Data I don’t have persistence. I will appreciate if you can help me to setup Core Data.

Comment: Agree with Keyur that you need to do a basic tutorial. Learn how to create objects and save them.

Comment: I can create and save single entity. But as you can see from my example I have two entities. AFAIK that is the only way to emulate arrays. The linked tutorial only talks about single entity. Also for my example order or Job detail is important.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this. May be it's useful to you...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the screenshots that your setup is correct. Link details with jobs like this.

```
detail1.parent = job
detail2.parent = job 
context.save(nil)
```

Get all details for a job like this

```
job.details
```

This is unordered, but you can sort them using `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`.

```
let sortedDetails = job.details.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors(
  [NSSortDescriptor(key:"date" ascending: false)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have slight problem because sometimes dates are same, is there a way to order them according to order they added or should I use some index variable and set it ? Also the code you wrote implies that I should get details into array. I am trying to use Core Data alone to use in tableview. Basically, I want to add details with *addDetail* function to Core Data and fetch Job Names with details to populate tableView. I will appreciate if you can write me a simple boiler plate code or direct me an example. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry but this platform is not for getting boiler-plate code. You will have to write that yourself. The code I have provided solves the question you asked originally. If you are struggling with this, I recommend to use `NSFetchedResultsController` (consult the docs) which is specifically built for displaying Core Data objects in table views.